# Lists, functions, while loop, if/else/elif statements

Tags: python, list

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# custom function checkValid
def checkValid(chooseGenre):

    # create a list of valid genres
    genres = ["house" , "trance" , "techno" ]
    for genre in genres :
        if chooseGenre == genre :
            return True
        else:
            return False

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
while True :

    # prompt user to specify what genre of music they want to choose and save into a variable  
    chooseGenre = input("Which of the following genres of electronic dance music would you like to choose? ")

    # the user chooses a valid genre
    if checkValid(chooseGenre) == True :


        # user chooses house
        if (chooseGenre == "house") :
            edmMusic = genreHouse()

        # user chooses trance
        elif (chooseGenre == "trance") :
            edmMusic = genreTrance()

        # user chooses techno
        elif (chooseGenre == "techno") :
            edmMusic = genreTechno()               

        break 

    else :

        # user chooses an invalid genre
        print("Not a valid genre. Please try again. ")
```

I'm having trouble getting the genres "techno" and "trance" to be recognized as valid genres. The output for these two genres is

```
"Not a valid genre. Please try again. "
```

I can't figure out why only the `'house'` genre is accepted.

Comment: Please introduce the problem before pasting your code and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Describe how the code does not work and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is get "trance" and "techno" to not print out "Not a valid genre. Please try again. " this is because they ARE valid genres. the only one the works perfectly is "house"

Comment: i just want to know if I wrote the wrong usage of elif statements or anything else. the program runs but for "trance" and "techno", it says it's not valid when it is clearly in the list of valid genres to be evaluated True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in your function `checkValid`. What you are trying to do is perform a membership test, but what you are actually doing is looking at the first item of the list `["house" , "trance" , "techno" ]` and then return `True` if your function argument is `'house'` and `False` otherwise.

Remember that a function returns for good when it encounters a `return` statement.

You can write your function like this:

```
def checkValid(chooseGenre):
    return chooseGenre in {'house', 'trance', 'techno'}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this works! :D

Answer (score 0):

You `return False` at the first test.  If I were to ask "Are you one of 10, 12, 25, or 30 years of age?"  You could test, "Am I 10?" "No".  "I am not one of those."  That doesn't make sense.  You need to go to the end:

```
for genre in genres:
    if chooseGenre == genre:
        return True
return False # We don't get to this point unless all of them were False.
```

There is a simpler way, however:

```
return chooseGenre in genres
```

Comment: so what you're saying is I don't need the "return False" statement and replace it with "return chooseGenre in genres" ?

Comment: That is correct.  You can replace the whole loop with that.  timgeb shows you the whole function in his answer.